# Windows file manager with last visited folders history

Tags: windows-7, file-management

Is there a file manager for Windows that has a running history of the last X folders you visited?

Comment: Which ones have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried DirectoryOpus, xyPlorer, xPlorer2, FreeComander, CubicExplorer, DoubleCommander, QT-Tabbar, Q-Dir, Explorer++, UltraExplorer and probably several others too.  This was over a period of several years in the past.  I've just been on the search on and off and just thought of asking the collective intelligence here.

Comment: In 2024, for Windows 10 and up, Brows has a panel history with each previously visited location. https://brows.app

Comment: Brows looks interesting, will give it a whirl thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Windows 7 but I remember you can access the recently visited folder by right-clicking the icon on the superbar.

**Edit:** You may want to look at **Unreal Commander**. Alt+Down shows the history of directory visited even after you close the file manager.

Comment: I'm looking for a file manager -- this isn't really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Edited my answer to suggest a file manager

Comment: (+1) should help you towards getting sufficient rep to participate more fully.

Answer (score 0):

Directory Opus and XYplorer have recent folder lists. In XYplorer it's in Go > Recent Locations... and I know it's in Directory Opus but don't have it installed at the moment so I can't tell you where exactly.